# Movie IMDb Top 250 Classifier Code -- problem with printing ArrayList with *.get(<OptionMovie>);

Tags: java, eclipse, web-scraping, arraylist

I am trying to make a code that works kinda like a 'classifier' of the top 250 movies from IMDb. So, I did some web scraping through Imdb's website. The code works like this: in the first part I am asking the user if he wants the top250 imdb all time movie list to be shown (and type '1' for 'yes') and in the second part I am showing the possible genres for movies: "Action, Mystery,Thriller,Comedy etc.".
Ok, the user can choose one of the options below and then in the output console it will be shown the title movies that are in bond with the respective genre.
Now, I made a part in the code where the user can select one of the title movies if they find it interesting and after they chose it some information like the description of the movie would be shown.
But, there comes the problem: the System.out.println(get.list1()) doesn't work, it does not show anything in the console output, Eclipse simply terminates the action.

this part of the code looks like this:

case 21:
System.out.println("Western: ");
final Document document211=Jsoup.connect("https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?genres=western&groups=top_250&sort=user_rating,desc").get();
Elements div211 = document211.select("div.lister-item-content");
for(Element e : div211.select("h3")) {
String title=e.select("h3.lister-item-header a").text();
list.add(title);
System.out.println(k+" "+title);
k++;

```
        }
        for(Element e : div211.select("p")) {
            String description=e.select("p.text-muted").text();
            System.out.println(description);
            list1.add(description);
            p++;
        }
        break;
}

    System.out.println("Have u found any interesting title and you want more details about it? (Type '1')");
    int option2=input.nextInt();
    ok=false;
    switch(option2){
        
    case 1:
        ok=true;
        System.out.println("Introduce the order number of the title: ");
    }
    Scanner input2=new Scanner(System.in);
    int optionMovie=input2.nextInt();

    if(ok) {
        
        if(optionMovie>=0 && optionMovie<=list1.size()) {
            
            System.out.println(list1.get(optionMovie));
        }
    
            // here the description movie should be shown but nothing shows.
        }
    }
```

in the console the output is like this:
0 Cel bun, cel r?u, cel urât
1 Once Upon a Time in the West
2 Django dezlantuit
3 Pentru Cativa Dolari in Plus
4 Necrutatorul
5 Comoara din Sierra Madre
6 Goana dupa Aur

u are asked if u want more details about a title and u type '1' for 'yes' and then u type the respective number of the title (from 0-6 in this case) and then I want to be shown the respective description of the respective title. but list1.get(optionMovie); doesn't work in console, and the ArrayList is created.
Hope u understood my problem!
Hoping for some solutions to fix this.

Comment: Please fix the code in your question and delete your answer posting the image as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fNYC.png)

Here I have a little photo of my output and the part of the code where I have the problem.